# Convertir archivo.html externo a json con el framework Vue js

Tags: html, json, vue.js

Tengo un archivo html (tablas.html) y quiero acceder a él con Vue Js y convertirlo a JSON para poder tratarlo.

El objetivo es obtener los datos de una web mediante la descarga en un archivo .html y buscar la información que se necesite y mostrarlo.

Por ahora tengo el contenido del archivo en una variable (fileDir):

```
var fileDir = require('../tablas.html')
```

¿Alguna idea?, ¿es posible?, y ¿cómo?.

Por si sirve. He encontrado como convertir html del propio componente de Vue y convertirlo a json, pero no sé como hacerlo en mí caso.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881303/convert-table-html-to-json/30881496#30881496

Edito:
El código de tablas.html es

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>Tablas:</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabla_content">
            <span class="titulo">Tabla 1:</span>
            <table class="tabla">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Orden</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fila">
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">1</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">Carolina</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">fernández</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fila">
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">2</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">Óscar</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">García</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span class="titulo">Tabla 2:</span>
            <table class="tabla">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Orden</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="fila">
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">1</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">Miguel</td>
                        <td class="elementoCompleto">Hernández</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto captura del contenido del archivo tablas.html.

[image: **tablas.html**]

Comment: Podrias pasar tu imagen a codigo para ayudarte mejor? Y porqué lo deseas realizar desde un archivo externo, si Vue permite incluir HTML y Javascript en el mismo archivo del componente?

Comment: @JoséBardales
Sorry, ya lo he editado con el código.
Lo que quiero es buscar información en una web.
Estoy empezando con esto del desarrollo y con Vue js y no sé si será correcto.
Pero lo que he pensado es:
- Descargar el archivo.html (aún no sé cómo lo haré)
- Convertirlo a JSON para poder recorrerlo y obtener las filas que necesito.